# Advection Equation with $f(x)\cdot u(x,t)$ source term

Tags: partial-differential-equations

I'm working through solving a form of the advection equation for a course I'm taking.  Without going into the specifics of my particular problem, the PDE has the general form shown below.  I've outlined my attempt at trying to solve it below, but given the conditions that I have for the problem, my result doesn't seem to make too much sense:

$$
u_t + cu_x = f(x)u
$$
$$
\begin{matrix}u(0,t) = u_0 & and & u(x,0) = 0 \end{matrix}
$$

I understand how to solve PDEs of the form $u_t + c u_x = u$ using the method of characteristics by taking $\tau = t$ and $\xi = x - ct$ to get the expression:

$$
u_\tau = u
$$
which can easily be integrated to yield
$$ 
\ln u(\xi, \tau) = \tau + f(\xi) \implies u(x,t) = g(x-ct)e^t
$$

However, when I have $f(x)u$ as a source instead of just $u$, I find that
$$
u_\tau = f(x) u
$$

Initially, my thought was to simply integrate this the same way resulting in
$$
\ln u = f(x)\tau + g(\xi)
$$
but since $\xi = x - ct$, $x = \xi + ct = \xi + c\tau$, which means that we actually have
$$
\frac{1}{u} u_\tau = f(\xi + c\tau)
$$
and integrating results in 
$$
\ln u = \frac{1}{c} F(\xi + c\tau) + g(\xi)
$$
$$
\implies u = g(x-ct)e^{\frac{1}{c} F(x)}
$$
where $F(\cdot)$ denoting the integral of $f(\cdot)$ w.r.t. $\tau$.  In the case of a simple $f(x)$ which only has linear terms in powers of $x$ (i.e. $a_0 + a_1x + a_2x^2 + ...$), the result takes the general form
$$
u = g(x-ct)e^{c_1t + c_2t^2 + ...}
$$
Then the initial condition and boundary condition result in 
\begin{align}
g(x) = 0 \\ 
g(-ct)e^{c_1t + x_2t^2 + ...} = u_o
\end{align}

With this, I'm not sure where to go as far as visualizing what happens at a fixed x as time evolves.  I'm used to the initial condition being $u_0$ resulting in a solution of the form $u(x,t) = u_0(x)*decay$.  These conditions and my result have me questioning whether I did this right, so any input would be appreciated.

Comment: You're fine until step where you integrated $u_\tau=f(x)u$. Fix your integration and it will work out fine.

Comment: Am I missing something simple then?  Isn't it true that integrating both sides of $\frac{1}{u} u_\tau = f(\xi + c\tau)$ results in $\ln u$ on the left and $\frac{1}{c} F(\xi + c\tau)$ on thr ight?  Taking the derivative of this result, anyway, results in $\frac{1}{u} = f(\xi + c\tau)$, which is what we were trying to integrate, no?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's suppose $u(x,0)=g(x)$ instead of $0$. Our characteristic is $x(t)=ct+x^0$. Then we have,$$\dot{z}(t)=f(ct+x^0)z(t)$$
Integrating yields,
$$z(t)=z(0)e^{\int_0^t f(cs+x^0)ds}$$
Where $z(0)=g(x^0)$
Therefore,$$u(x,t)=g(x-ct)e^{\int_0^t f(c(s-t)+x)ds}$$
When $x-ct>0$. So you'll have to do another case for the characteristic hits the $\{x=0\}$ boundary instead. Does that help? Can you understand the different notation?

Comment: Isn't that the same result as what I have?  $g(x-ct)e^{ \int{f(c(s-t)+x) ds}}$ is the same as $g(x-ct)e^{ \int {f(\eta + Vs) ds}}$ where $\eta = x-Vt$.

Comment: Then you're right. There's a lot of text there, I didn't read all of it. Sorry.

Comment: If you're unsure in future, you can plug it into initial PDE to check result. You mentioned difficulty visualizing, I find it more instructive to plot characteristics to visualize rather than looking at the explicit solution.