# Advection equation with source u/x

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations

I am trying to solve following equation:

$$
u_t + u_x + \frac{u}{x} = 0
$$

With initial condition:
$$
u(x,0) = 0
$$

And with boundary condition given at *x* = 15:
$$
u(15,t) = sin (wt)
$$

I tried to transform it to the form of:
$$
u_t + u_x =- \frac{u}{x}
$$

And solve it with method of characteristics. However, 1) I am not sure how to treat x on the right side (all online examples have source term either *x* or *u*, never both). 2) I am not sure when and how to insert this boundary condition in this equation?

My kind of solution always include *e*, and solution provided by tutor does not contain any *e* terms.

I tried following this example [Advection Equation with $f(x)\cdot u(x,t)$ source term](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/317696/advection-equation-with-fx-cdot-ux-t-source-term), however I did not understand it completely, specifically part "which can easily be integrated to yield..."

Answer (score 1):

Just follow the method of characteristics, which in your case reads:

$$dt = dx = \frac{du}{-u/x}.$$

From 1st and 2nd we have $t-x = c_1$ is a characteristic of the PDE. From 2nd and 3rd we would have that $u = c_2/x$ is the other characteristic  curve. Put $c_2$ as a function of $c_1$ and you are done!

Cheers!

Comment: Thank you for fast reply, but I am not sure what do you mean by "From 2nd and 3rd we would have that u=c2e−x2/2"

From 2nd and 3rd I get dx/x = - (du/u), so it yield ln x = ln u, i.e. u = x + constant?

Comment: You are totally right! (except for the sign)

Comment: Heh, thanks, but that does not lead me a long way. Thx anyway, I will try to use ideas provided above.

Comment: Hi @nevermind! Consider accepting the answer in order to completely close your question. Thanks in advance!